# How do you install blackcoin on a headless server or VPS?

Tags: installation, blackcoin

Could somebody tell me the commands to get blackcoin installed over the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to slightly modify the following steps for your needs:

1. ssh or log into the machine
2. Make sure that git is installed.

   sudo apt-get install git
3. Clone the github repo

   git clone https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin.git
4. Follow the instructions from the [installation documentation](https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt)  which are:
5. Install the dependencies.

   sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libqrencode-dev
6. Run the makefile which will compile the program from the source we just downloaded.

   cd blackcoin/src
   make -f makefile.unix
7. Run the newly created binary.

   ./blackcoind

There is also a #blackcoin irc channel on freenode where there are friendly blackcoiners happy to walk you through installation.